# Is it possible to report the deployed App version with the cf CLI

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there a Cloud Foundry cli command parameter or cli plugin that reports the version of Apps running in a given Space? I don't see anything in the cli reference guide.

Comment: By "app version", what do you mean exactly? Are you talking about an ID that's assigned by the app developer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the application's version directly using the cf cli. The cf cli only talks to the Cloud Controller and the Cloud Controller doesn't have this level of introspection into your application.

The closest thing that comes to mind is Pivotal's Apps Manager, which can integrate with Spring Boot apps that use Actuator to display the git version/build info of your app. See here.

https://docs.run.pivotal.io/console/using-actuators.html#view-build

This is done through the Spring Boot actuators though, so to access from the command line you would need to run `curl` or `wget`, rather than `cf`.

Aside from that, you could hack this together by setting an environment variable with your application, like `cf set-env <app> APP_VERSION f3de7f0`. If you did that for every app, you could retrieve the env variables with `cf env <app>` and see the app versions. You could even write a short script to pull for all the apps in a space.

Hope that helps!